# What is <C-j> default action in insert mode in vim? Why I can't use it for YCM

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I found strange behavior about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>. I called it strange because I can't get what action it does and. I tried some way to get what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> really do with this:

```
:map <C-j>
:imap <C-j>
:vmap <C-j>
:verbose map <C-j>
:verbose imap <C-j>
:verbose vmap <C-j>
```

they all give `no mapping found`.

And then I tried this:

```
:unmap <C-j>
```

it gives me `E13: No such mapping`

I want to use it in YCM with:

```
`let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<C-j>']`
`let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-k>']`
```

`<C-k>` does work but `<C-j>` doesn't. Instead, `<C-j>` (in insert mode) behave like `<Enter>`. So, what is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> actually do in vim? And why I can't use it?

Comment: `:help i_CTRL-J` gives: `Begin new line.`

Comment: Ah .. I see. So,can it be unmapped? Because, I think `Enter` is enough to do that (begin new line).

Comment: Sorry, I also do not know why it can not be used. As for usage, I prefer Ctrl-j because Enter key position is far at the right side :-)

Comment: `<C-j>` is the equivalent of `<NL>` which is how vim represents `<Nul>` internally. When used in a mapping, `<C-j>` actually sends `<C-@>` which is another representation of `<Nul>`. Replacing `<C-j>` with `<C-@>` will probably work. (yes, it's a mess.)

Comment: @Bagol `<C-j>` can be remapped, e.g. I have it remapped to `:bnext` and `<C-k>` mapped to `:bprev`